# adaptive card js rendering - card not supported

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I am trying to use the javascript rendering SDK to render my layout. 
My bot is returning a hero card with the following JSON in message.attachments.
the json is as below:

```
[
    {
        "contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
        "content":
            {
                "text":"Please select an option",
                "buttons":
                    [
                        {
                            "type":"a1",
                            "title":"1.Choice1",
                            "value":"1.Choice1"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "type":"a1",
                            "title":"2.Choice2",
                            "value":"2.Choice2"
                        }
                    ]
            }
    }
]
```

This renders fine in webchat, emulator...but in my custom rendering, the output of rendering is

```
"The specified card version is not supported."
```

i am loading the sdk from https://unpkg.com/adaptivecards/dist/adaptivecards.js

I would think if webchat supports it, then javascript SDK should render it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json object your bot responsed, is a hero card not an **Adaptive Card**. So the javascript sdk throw this execption.

An adaptive card must follow its shema, please refer to [Adaptive Card Renderer Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/display/implementingrenderer) for detailed rules.

Following is a validated sample:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Here is a ninja cat"
        },
        {
            "type": "Image",
            "url": "http://adaptivecards.io/content/cats/1.png"
        }
    ]
}
```